# Any way to play Majesty or Majesty 2 multiplayer cross-platform?

Tags: majesty-2, majesty

So I've been on a nostalgia fix recently, and have been hoping to get my girlfriend in on my old school gaming action. Unfortunately, she is a mac and I'm a PC, so our retro multiplayer exploits have been off to a slow start.

In particular, I'd love to play Majesty with her (preferably the original, but the 2nd would work too). Is there any way to do this? Would direct connection or LAN work cross-platform? Perhaps a third party service like hamachi? I'd try these options out myself, but I'd really hate to buy two copies of a games just to fail to be able to play it :-/

Comment: +1 I would love to know the answer to this. I love Majesty.

Comment: I'm not sure about the performance capabilities of the MAC, but have your tried installing a Windows Virtual Machine, and installing the game on that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this will work.

You can play mutilplayer majesty on Gameranger but neither Majesty one or two are listed as cross platform games:
http://www.gameranger.com/games/pcmac/

There are some people who mention using Hamachi for mulitplayer but I think they are all using windows. See comment 7 on this page : http://steamcommunity.com/app/73230/discussions/0/864945309934703788/

The Majesty 2 Gold manual is available here:
http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/25990/manuals/Majesty_Manual_HD.pdf?t=1332176441
but I couldn't find any helpful info in it.

You might have to try a different game! Blizzard games all work cross platform.

Answer (score 0):

Majesty should work perfectly fine cross platform.  I know they use Gamespy Arcade for online play, but if you select "LAN" or "Local" (can't quite remember which it is called, but should be obvious) it won't use Gamespy and will allow multi-platform play. PC developers aren't like console devs, you can own it for Windows, Mac, or Linux/Unix and still play with everyone.